# Macro in Excel 2016 but gives me a compile error in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro that works on 2016, but when opened in 2010 throws up a compile error. The purpose of the macro is to export excel data into a pdf and attach it to a new email in outlook.

The VBA code is below. The error that occurs is on line 18, =Left, I've put it in bold.

I am somewhat new to VBA and I'm using a former colleagues macro, any help is appreciated!

The problem in the code is below, the error that is highlighted is the Left function. I can post the entire macro if neccessary.

```
' Define PDF filename
PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
PdfFile = PdfFile & ".pdf"
```

Comment: Open Tools - References and have a look. Does it say MISSING anywhere?

Comment: The references option is unable to be selected within the VBA interface.

Comment: If that's the case, you are either editing a cell or have a macro running. Or something else that is blocking VBE. Try restarting Excel if you can't find out what.

Comment: Opening the references menu, it doesn't say missing anywhere, darn!

Comment: The same question, but for the 2010 machine.

Comment: step thru the code.. what is the value of `i`?

Comment: How am I able to discern the value of i? I'm unfamiliar with VBA so an explanation in layman's terms would be very helpful...